# Digits & Squares

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, decimal-expansion, square-numbers

If $\overline{abcd} = (\overline{ab} + \overline{cd})^2$ and only $c$ can be $0$, find the sum of all possible values of $\overline{abcd}$.

$(A) 13850$

$(B) 14051$

$(C) 14742$

$(D) 14851$

$(E) 16051$

First I expanded the RHS to get $$100(a^2+c^2)+b^2+d^2+2(100ac+10ab+10ad+10bc+10cd+bd)=1000a+100b+10c+d$$

Since that didn't seem correct, I plugged in values and it looked like anything above $50^2$ didn't work. Any better ways?

EDIT: I found $99^2$ to work.

Ok, so I went full tryhard mode and literally bashed out everything from $32^2$ to $75^2$. Since the answer choices mean that the last one's in that range, maybe I miscalculated, but I didn't find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modding by 99, we find that this becomes solving for $$n=n^2 \mod 99$$
$$n(n-1)=0\mod 99$$

Using Chinese remainder theorem, we find the solutions to be $1,45,55,99$. $1$ doesn't work, all other ones work, so the solution is: $45^2+55^2+99^2=14851$

Comment: yes i found that, but it said 'only c can be 0'. so should i just ignore that

Comment: It is to prevent the degenerated cases, such as $a=b=c=0$, $d=1$. It's just a clarification for do we count it if $c$ is $0$.